# Можно ли контролировать порядок отображения иконок расширений в Яндекс браузере?

Tags: chrome-extension, яндекс-браузер

Яндекс браузер показывает только 5 установленных расширений, остальные скрывает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне, как разработчику расширения, необходимо чтобы иконка моего расширения всегда отображалась, поскольку она анимированная и в этом есть определенная цель. В этой связи у меня два вопроса:

1. По какому вообще принципу формируется порядок отображения расширений в Яндекс браузере?
2. Можно ли это контролировать? Можно ли иконку своего расширения показывать первой в очереди?

Answer (score 0):

Интересовался подобным вопросом, но решения по принудительному позиционированию так и не нашел. 
Вероятно Яндекс Браузер использует тот же алгоритм что и Chromium.

Но в Chromium такая возможность отсутствует во избежании навязчивости.